# No ability to publish newer build for external testers - how to revoke "In Review" status?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a 5 builds in testflight, but have no ability to publish last one.

> You can only submit one build from version 1.0.0 to Beta App Review. Once the build you submitted is approved, you can submit additional builds.

Question is:

- How to revoke "Waiting for Review" for before-last-build ?
- How to set "Waiting for Review" status for latest build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there is possible to do more elegant way the same but...

## Hack solution

1. ExternalTestingGroup -> Testers List -> Edit -> (select all testers) -> Remove
2. Add the same testers to the same group

This resolved my issue

---

If anybody know better way - please post it.

It's insane to do the same on each build.